# Use paramenter in raw-Query in LIKE-Statement

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 8 and I have created the following query:

```
DB::connection($con)->select( DB::raw("
select
    distinct c.id as companies_id,
    name,
    symbol
from
    product t
left outer join companies c on
    c.id = t.companies_id
where symbol like '%:field%' or name like '%:field%'
order by
    symbol asc;"),
            array('field' => $field)
        );
```

The above version does not work.

However, when using the following it works.

```
DB::connection($con)->select( DB::raw("
select
    distinct c.id as companies_id,
    name,
    symbol
from
    product t
left outer join companies c on
    c.id = t.companies_id
where symbol like '%$field%' or name like '%$field%'
order by
    symbol asc;"));
```

The below version is not safe against sql injections. Any suggestions how to use the above query with a parameter within the like statement?

I appreciate your replies

Comment: You don't need to use `DB::raw()` method. You can directly use raw select query in `select()` method which takes two parameters, one your query and another is binding parameters like this
`select($query, ['symbol' => '%$field%', 'name' => '%$filed%'])`

Comment: @Haridarshan How would you code the `$query`?

Comment: here `$query` is your select query which you're using in `DB::raw()` method. Only change in this query is you no longer need to hardcode the value directly to avoid sql injection, instead of that you can use `symbol like :symbol or name like :name`